How do I replace HttpContext.Current in .NET Framework 4.5.2?
I have a component library called in an application as a web api repository base to interface with an api that handles all database interactions.
I use HttpContext.Current to get things like the current profile or the current Request.
Since it's going away, I want to remove it from my code but I will want to be able to collect information to send to my api.
Is there an alternative method of accessing the application instance my code is running in other than HttpContext.Current?

I gather you still have access to HttpContext? if yes then wouldn't it suffice to access HttpContext.Session and HttpContext.Request. or is it missing something? docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext?view=netframework-4.8.1

HttpContext .Current is a static property of the class HttpContext that represents the current instance of the application class in which a calling code block is running.
Session and Request are only available through HttpContext.Current because I am calling HttpContext inside a dll that is installed through Nuget.

What do you mean, "it's going away"? It's still there in .NET Framework 4.8.1.

"Since it's going away," Not unless you update to .NET and ASP.NET Core. I wouldn't worry about it until then when you will have to make a lot of other changes too.
